# Kali Linux gray screen after logon and mouse stuck

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux

I've just made a dual boot with Kali and Windows 10. Kali starts normally and shows me the login screen, but when I login, it simply sticks on a gray screen and I can't move the mouse.

I've tried starting Kali in console mode, (I can login as root there) and I saw that this can be caused by missing video card drivers, but I can't even connect to my network to download them. when I type:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid [NETWORK] key s:[PASS]
```

it gives me:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

wlan0 is actually up...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Xavierjazz what can cause the wireless problem or if threres another way to fiz the gray screen

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing this same issue (gray screen after login). I was able to resolve it by disabling the nouveau drivers.

Create a file /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf and paste the following lines:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
options nouveau.modeset=0
```

source: http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/installing-nvidia-on-kali-2.0/

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to connect to a WPA or WPA2 network, you actually need to use wpasupplicant. iwconfig is for Open and WEP only. You can find additional information on the superuser question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/42460/can-you-explain-how-to-understand-what-the-iwconfig-command-displays-in-ubuntu/353818#353818) the AskUbuntu question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line), and the StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119446/iwconfig-connect-network-via-wifi-on-terminal).

An alternative would be to plug into ethernet and let it update. Kali Linux usually takes a little while to update the first time and you usually have to run it a few times so don't worry if it seems like its run for a while.